# Map local IP 127.0.1.2 in different directory in Apache Server

Tags: linux, apache-httpd, apache-virtualhost

In my localhost (Apache Server), I have two `VirtualHost` in port 80 pointing to different directory.

Here is my two conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot /home/myuser/project_1/

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName project2
    DocumentRoot /home/myuser/project_2/

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

And in my `/etc/hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.2 project2
```

Now when I type `http://localhost` it maps to `project_1` directory and for `http://project2/` it maps to `project_2` directory. Things are fine here but if I type `127.0.1.2` it always maps to first `project_1` instead of `project_2` directory i.e it maps to `localhost` instead of `project2` url.

Why is this? How I can do such reverse mapping?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your virtual host configurations, you are using name based virtual hosts as you specify `ServerName`.  This means that a configuration would only load when the "Host" header in the client request matches.  The default behavior of Apache when it cannot match the requested host with any configured virtual hosts is to load the first configured virtual host it can find.

There are many options to get the right content, one is to adjust the "Host" header in your request to match the `ServerName` you are trying to reach.  Another would be to add the IP address as a `ServerAlias` or you could switch to IP based virtual hosts and configure things that way.

Comment: Thanks. ServerAlias method worked. First one, i didn't understand. Haha